# Can't use apt-get upgrade - dpkg: error processing iwlwifi-firmware

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, dpkg, iwlwifi

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. Whenever I try to run `apt-get upgrade`, the upgrade fails:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  google-musicmanager-beta
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up iwlwifi-firmware (3.15.1.6wataugafour2) ...
Leaving 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
`/usr/share/iwlwifi-dkms/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode' -> `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode'
Leaving 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
`/usr/share/iwlwifi-dkms/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode' -> `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode'
Leaving 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
`/usr/share/iwlwifi-dkms/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode' -> `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode'
Leaving 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6050-4.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6050-4.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
`/usr/share/iwlwifi-dkms/firmware/iwlwifi-6050-4.ucode' -> `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6050-4.ucode'
Leaving 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-100-5.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-100-5.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
`/usr/share/iwlwifi-dkms/firmware/iwlwifi-100-5.ucode' -> `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-100-5.ucode'
Leaving 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
`/usr/share/iwlwifi-dkms/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode' -> `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode'
Leaving 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
`/usr/share/iwlwifi-dkms/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode' -> `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode'
Leaving 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
`/usr/share/iwlwifi-dkms/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode' -> `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode'
Leaving 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
`/usr/share/iwlwifi-dkms/firmware/iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode' -> `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode'
Leaving 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
`/usr/share/iwlwifi-dkms/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode' -> `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode'
Leaving 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
`/usr/share/iwlwifi-dkms/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode' -> `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode'
Leaving 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-135-6.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-135-6.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
`/usr/share/iwlwifi-dkms/firmware/iwlwifi-135-6.ucode' -> `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-135-6.ucode'
Leaving 'diversion of /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.bseq to /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.bseq.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
`/usr/share/iwlwifi-dkms/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.bseq' -> `/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.bseq'
Leaving 'diversion of /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq to /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
`/usr/share/iwlwifi-dkms/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq' -> `/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq'
Leaving 'diversion of /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq to /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
`/usr/share/iwlwifi-dkms/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq' -> `/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq'
Leaving 'diversion of /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.1.2d.d.bseq to /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.1.2d.d.bseq.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
`/usr/share/iwlwifi-dkms/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.1.2d.d.bseq' -> `/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.1.2d.d.bseq'
Leaving 'diversion of /lib/firmware/intel/fw_sst_0f28.bin-48kHz_i2s_master to /lib/firmware/intel/fw_sst_0f28.bin-48kHz_i2s_master.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
`/usr/share/iwlwifi-dkms/firmware/intel/fw_sst_0f28.bin-48kHz_i2s_master' -> `/lib/firmware/intel/fw_sst_0f28.bin-48kHz_i2s_master'
Leaving 'diversion of /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq to /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
`/usr/share/iwlwifi-dkms/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq' -> `/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq'
Leaving 'diversion of /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.2.27.d.bseq to /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.2.27.d.bseq.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
`/usr/share/iwlwifi-dkms/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.2.27.d.bseq' -> `/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.2.27.d.bseq'
dpkg-divert: error: `diversion of /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.bseq to /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.bseq.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms' clashes with `diversion of /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.bseq to /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.bseq.oem-wireless-bluetooth-intel-7260 by oem-wireless-bluetooth-intel-7260-dkms'
dpkg: error processing iwlwifi-firmware (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 iwlwifi-firmware
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

There seems to be an update of `iwlwifi-firmware` hanging in there which cannot be resolved. However, `dpkg --configure -a` doesn't output anything. I've tried to remove this package to attempt a clean install afterwards, but `apt-get remove --purge iwlwifi-firmware` fails similarly:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  iwlwifi-firmware*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 15.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 380078 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing iwlwifi-firmware ...
removed `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode'
Removing 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
removed `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode'
Removing 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
removed `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode'
Removing 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
removed `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6050-4.ucode'
Removing 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6050-4.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6050-4.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
removed `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-100-5.ucode'
Removing 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-100-5.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-100-5.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
removed `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode'
Removing 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
removed `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode'
Removing 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
removed `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode'
Removing 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
removed `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode'
Removing 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
removed `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode'
Removing 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
removed `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode'
Removing 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
removed `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-135-6.ucode'
Removing 'diversion of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-135-6.ucode to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-135-6.ucode.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
removed `/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.bseq'
Removing 'diversion of /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.bseq to /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.bseq.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
removed `/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq'
Removing 'diversion of /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq to /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
removed `/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq'
Removing 'diversion of /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq to /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
removed `/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.1.2d.d.bseq'
Removing 'diversion of /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.1.2d.d.bseq to /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.1.2d.d.bseq.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
removed `/lib/firmware/intel/fw_sst_0f28.bin-48kHz_i2s_master'
Removing 'diversion of /lib/firmware/intel/fw_sst_0f28.bin-48kHz_i2s_master to /lib/firmware/intel/fw_sst_0f28.bin-48kHz_i2s_master.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
removed `/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq'
Removing 'diversion of /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq to /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
removed `/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.2.27.d.bseq'
Removing 'diversion of /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.2.27.d.bseq to /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.2.27.d.bseq.iwlwifi by iwlwifi-dkms'
rm: cannot remove `/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.bseq': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing iwlwifi-firmware (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 iwlwifi-firmware
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The output of `ls /lib/firmware/*.ucode`:

```
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode  /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-100-5.ucode   /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-105-6.ucode   /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-135-6.ucode   /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode  /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode  /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode  /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-6.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode  /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode
```

And my `sources.list`:

```
#############################################################
################### OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS ###################
#############################################################

###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I'll be happy to supply any missing information.

Answer (score 0):

`iwlwifi-firmware` is not a package from Ubuntu repositories.

You've downloaded it from somewhere and installed it. This package conflicts with the official `linux-firmware` package.

After you installed that `iwlwifi-firmware`, you manually deleted some files from it and broke the package.

The easiest way is to re-install `iwlwifi-firmware` and then purge it.